# Printing multiple pages on one page in landscape orientation

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

I'm trying to print four landscape-oriented pages of a document in a grid on one page in *landscape*-orientation using VBA with:

```
ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientationLandscape
ActiveDocument.PrintOut PrintZoomRow:=2, PrintZoomColumn:=2
```

This however is printing the four small landscape-oriented pages in a grid on a *portrait*-oriented page, which leaves them too small and with too much free space between them vertically.

I looked at the documentation for `PrintOut`, but didn't find anything concerning orientation.
I tried reversing the order of the `PrintZoom`s.
I also tried manually configuring the width and height of the printed paper with `PrintZoomPaperWidth` and -`Height`, which lead to the small pages being cut off and the printing one still in portrait mode.

Comment: Word works the same using VBA as it does via the UI. Your first step should be to see if you can do it in the UI. If you can you should also be able to do it via VBA. If not, than VBA won’t work either.

Comment: Ok, I assumed it would work in UI as I have an example copy, but trying it for myself using every option I could it also doesn't work. Nice to know it's at least not my lack of ~programming~ googling skills but just a thing word doesn't do at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just doesn't seem to be possible in the current version of Office (2019), neither with code nor the UI.

As a workaround, one could take screenshots, change the orientation to portrait and paste them in rotated 90° or use rotated textboxes in Word.
Alternatively and probably much easier, create a PDF and use a PDF reader capable of printing this way, e.g. *Adobe Reader*.